# Print to pos printers from a browser (web app in php)

Tags: php, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to directly print to a printer, like POS printer, over the web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174555/whats-the-best-way-to-directly-print-to-a-printer-like-pos-printer-over-the-w)

I want to print some simple text to a POS printer (many different models) from a browser. 
There might be different models but the sure thing is that the printer will be connected into a windows computer and have its drivers installed. The printer might be connected via usb, serial or ethernet.
So, I want the user of the Windows computer to be able to press a button (one click) in my web application and print to the specific POS printers.
The web app is written in php and uses jquery.
So what I am asking, is how is this possible, and which is the easiest and best way to do that.
Should I use javascript or what else? Is there a library?
Will I face compatibility issues, if there are multiple pos printer models?

Will the following do the work I need?

http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/